# How do I design functions that work with user-defined collections?

Tags: scala, scala-collections

I am having problems declaring an empty collection - I cannot use `Nil` as it produces a subtype...

```
def partiallyReduceString[S <: SeqLike[String, S]](reduction: String, seq: S): (String, S) =
  if (seq.nonEmpty)
    ...
  else
    (reduction, Nil)
```

I also tried `CanBuildFrom`, but I just get compile time errors...

```
def partiallyReduceString ... (implicit bf: CanBuildFrom[S, String, S]): (String, S) =
  if (seq.nonEmpty)
    ...
  else
    (reduction, bf().result())
```

> Cannot construct a collection of type S with elements of type String
>   based on a collection of type S.

Answer (score 2):

The problem is that the second element of your tuple should be of type S, which can be viewed as a SeqLike collection, but not the reverse. So even bf cannot help in this case.

Another point is that whatever you put in a result, S could be of type `List` or `Array`, but this cannot be viewed at compile time. You may want to define another constraint by specifying a way to create an empty collection of type S independently.

```
import scala.collection.SeqLike
implicit val emptyList = () => List()
implicit val emptyArray[T] = () => Array[T]()
def partiallyReduceString[S <: SeqLike[String, S]](reduction: String, seq: S)(implicit empty: () => S): (String, S) = {
  if (seq.nonEmpty)
    ???
  else
    (reduction, empty())
  }
```

Comment: Very good point. Assuming I changed it from a view bound to a standard constraint - that problem would surely go away - but I still have the compile time issue for CanBuildFrom

Comment: I have removed the view bound from the example to shift focus to the main problem :)

Comment: 'S could be of type List or Set' - not sure I understand: Set isn't a subtype of SeqLike, is it?

Comment: indeed. I corrected this. Perhaps Set can be viewed as a seqlike through implicit conversion, though.

Comment: I only know as I have a diagram of Scala type hierarchy tattooed on my forearm :P